# Can't copy text from a protected pdf file using Adobe reader

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a techincal pdf document from a third party source that I needed to copy a small amount of complilcated text from. I selected the text and found the copy option was greyed out. I looked at the properties and it seemed to be protected against copying. I wanted to copy the text rather than retype it as it was a bit complicated and I wanted to avoid typos.

Comment: If you wanted to post the answer yourself to help other community members, you should add the answer as the answer (a separate post) and not inside the question.

Comment: Yes thanks ZygD. That's what I tried to do but it wouldn't let me. All the answers and solutions in the original post didn't work for me. Then I found this solution that worked, so I wanted to add it to the answers. But the system refused to let me add it.

Comment: @davehants I think you misunderstood: you should post the answer below as an answer to your question and not as part of the question like you have here. The system will prevent you from posting comments if you don't have enough rep but you should be able to post an answer below a question without restriction afaik. If I remember correctly, I started off posting answers and didn't post my first question until much later.

Answer (score 1):

If this pdf is not an image, use pdftotext command. It is built-in utility in Ubuntu. If the pdf is an image file, you need to convert it to jpg and then recognize it with tesseract.

```
convert-im6.q16 -density 300 yourfile.pdf yourfile.jpg
tesseract -l en youfile.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening the file in an alternative PDF application, such as a browser, can be a simple way to get around SOME protections that may be applied to a PDF.

If the PDF content is a picture (it was scanned, for instance) this may not work and you'd need a tool with OCR (optical character recognition) to analyze the picture and generate the text from it.